# How can I edit my data in Core Data Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm developing an iOS contacts app. I don't know how to use Core Data but I learned a little bit and was able to create data and display it on a tableview. But now I need some help. I'm looking for code that queries a Contact name in Core Data to check if this contact already exists. If it does, I need to edit this data, if not I need to create this data. Can someone help me?

I'm using this simple code to create data:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Contact", in: context)
let newEventWithTickets = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

var name = contact.name
var email = contact.email

newEventWithTickets.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
newEventWithTickets.setValue(email, forKey: "email")

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("Failed saving")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Core data edit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833063/core-data-edit-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that you can consider is using `NSPredicate`. Essentially, you create conditions (name & email) to check in your `managedContext` to find entities that much the specific query.

Here is a rough draft on how to approach it:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<>(entityName: )

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:)

        do {
            data = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print ("Did not fetch")
        }
```

Once you get the data, use a conditional to compare what was inputed and what your query sends back.